# JSON async request

Tags: ios, iphone, json

i want to use async req to get json data, i am doing this by syncrouns already, but now requirement is change, but i am unable to modify this code to aync, beacuse i have to return NSdata

```
+ (NSString *)stringWithUrl:(NSURL *)url
{

//    if(kShowLog)
        NSLog(@"%@", url);

    NSURL *newURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url]];

    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:newURL
                                                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                            timeoutInterval:1];
    // Fetch the JSON response
    NSData *urlData;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;
//    NSOperationQueue *opQueue;

    // Make synchronous request
    urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try using [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com)?

Comment: You have two conflicting requirements: you shall return a NSString object which is the result of the operation, and your method shall be asynchronous. That's not possible. The caller cannot obtain the result of an asynchronous method _immediately_. Fix your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

call stringWithUrl on a 2. thread if you want to keep returning the data. (I'd go with async data

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(), ^{
     NSData *d = [self stringWithUrl:myURL];
     ...

     //update ui
     dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         ...
     });
});
```

Comment: you have to be aware that thread0 is NOT given NSData in a synchronous way here... thats the point of going async ;)

Answer (score 0):

a way that would work but is QUITE the hack (which apple employed in older APIs on the mac  all the time) would be to run the runloop while waiting:

hackisch :: but wraps async in sync given the completion block runs on the same thread then the runloop

```
    __block NSString *responseString = nil;
   [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myurl] 
                                      queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] 
                          completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:Data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if(!responseString) {
         responseString = @"";
    }
   }];

   while(!responseString) { 
       [NSRunloop currentRunloop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1];
   }

   return responseString;
```

Comment: written inline and hackisch but that will do the request async and wait (without blocking)

Comment: dateWithTimeIntervalFromNow not found class methods

Comment: I said I typed inline. I think you COULD spent 30s in the docs.. the method is `dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow` :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a separate thread for this process, Synchronous call of getting json data will block your main thread.

I'm changing your code to do asynchronous operation for getting json data from web service.

```
+ (void)stringWithUrl:(NSURL *)url
{

 dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
 dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    //    if(kShowLog)
    NSLog(@"%@", url);

    NSURL *newURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url]];

    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:newURL
                                                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                            timeoutInterval:1];
    // Fetch the JSON response
    NSData *urlData;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;
    //    NSOperationQueue *opQueue;

    // Make synchronous request
    urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        //Here you have to put your code, which you wanted to get executed after your data successfully retrived.
        //This block will get executed after your request data load to urlData.
    });

 });

}
```

Answer (score -1):

What's wrong with the Asynchronous then,

```
     NSString *responseString;
     NSOperationQueue *operation = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
       [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:operation completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
           NSLog(@"data %@", data);
        responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:Data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
       }];
     return responseString;
```

Comment: how can you return anything to return type void??????? why you are being upvote? your ans is not correct.plzz

Comment: what should return do here ;)

Comment: also you miss __block