# Obj-C synchronize an async method which using block callbacks

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, objective-c-blocks, synchronous

I have an async method called `getCount:` which goes to a web URL, counts some stuff, and invokes a callback with the count when it's done.

I have another method which is synchronous and needs to take those results, puts them into a message, and returns that message. Here are the two together:

```
- (NSString *)describe {
    __block bool gotCount = NO;
    [self getCount:^(int count) {
        NSLog(@"Got the count: %i", count);
        _count = count;  // _count is an ivar of the object with this method.
        gotCount = YES;
    }];
    // Pause here until the count has been fetched.
    while (!gotCount) {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.05];
    }
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The count is %i", _count];
}
```

My callback is never called when I try this. It never prints

```
Got the count 0
```

or any other value for count in this scenario.

If I comment out the while loop, that message does get printed out. So I know that the `getCount:` method works, there's just something wrong with my loop waiting for it to arrive.

I need `getCount:` to remain asynchronous (there's other places it gets used where that's more important) and I need `describe` to remain synchronous. How can I handle this?

Comment: _Why_ do you need `describe` to wait to return?

Comment: We can't really tell what's going on until we see the source of `getCount:` and know what queue `describe` is being run on.  My guess is that getCount: is scheduling the callback to run in the same serial queue as describe.

Comment: this form of actively waiting is quite bad .... it also wouldn't work if the sleep and the callback are on the same queue

Comment: Instead of a loop and sleeping, the preferred way to do this is to use dispatch semaphores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one possible thing: if your describe method is in the main thread then you call getCount method also from the main thread and all web callbacks are in the main thread. **BUT** you block the main thread with the thread sleep -> you can not get call back from the web to get a count.

Edited:

try to call getCount method from another thread. use e.g.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
   [self getCount:^(int count) {
       NSLog(@"Got the count: %i", count);
       _count = count;  // _count is an ivar of the object with this method.
       gotCount = YES;
   }];
});
```

Edited 2:

I tried this code and it works fine -> something probably wrong with the threads in your getCount method.

```
- (NSString *)describe {
    __block bool gotCount = NO;
    __block NSInteger _count;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.00];
        _count = 5;
        gotCount = YES;
    });
    // Pause here until the count has been fetched.
    while (!gotCount) {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.05];
    }
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The count is %li", _count];
}
```

Comment: How could I guarantee that this does't happen?

Comment: I tried the solution in your updated post. It didn't work for me.

Comment: I had a coworker look at my code and he revealed something to me: my code was, in fact, being called from the main thread. I was using a Parse method which had the word background in its name and took a block callback, and calling `describe` from that callback. That callback doesn't occur on a background thread though - the method runs on a background thread, and then calls your callback on the main thread. So sticking a `dispatch_async` in the callback around `describe` put it back in the background where I wanted it.

Answer (score 0):

a way that would work but is QUITE the hack (which apple employed in older APIs on the mac all the time) would be to run the runloop while waiting:

note: this relies on the callback being on the same queue as the describe method

**see: [JSON async request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141542/json-async-request) [SAME ISSUE]**

---

a self contained WORKING example:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface T : NSObject

- (NSString *)describe;
@end

@implementation T {
    int _count;
}

- (void)getCount:(void (^)(int c)) handler {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^ {
        sleep(5);
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            handler(55);
        });
    });
}

- (NSString *)describe {
    __block bool gotCount = NO;
    [self getCount:^(int count) {
        NSLog(@"Got the count: %i", count);
        _count = count;  // _count is an ivar of the object with this method.
        gotCount = YES;
    }];
    // Pause here until the count has been fetched.
    while (!gotCount) {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1]];
    }
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The count is %i", _count];
}

@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        T *t = [T new];
        NSLog(@"describe: %@", [t describe]);
    }
}
```

Comment: it is a hack but don't say it doesn't work ;) edited to show it